# Android: BroadcastReceiver to know via code when the screen in on/off

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, lifecycle

I've a Broadcast receiver:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {

          //Do something

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {

            Intent start=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(start);
        }
    }
}
```

And, in my activity, into onCreate():

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
ScreenReceiver mReceiver=new ScreenReceiver();
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

The problem is that, when my activity is displayed, the receiver performs correctly the action, but when it is in background, sometimes nothing happens.

What could be the issue?

Comment: See the answer to this post too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890363/broadcastreceiver-and-paused-activity

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, when your app goes into the background Android kills it to free up resources. Try [starting a foreground service attached to an ongoing notification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13129870/1069068) from your Activity, and register the BroadcastReceiver in that.

Comment: I tried to add it to a service:

    public class KillVPNService extends Service {
 ScreenReceiver mReceiver;
 
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
 filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
 mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
 registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}

and in my activity:

    startService(new Intent(this,KillVPNService.class));

But I did not solve the problem...